# AWS Cognito - User record not clearing in Cognito console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have created a user pool in the AWS Cognito console and I have 2 app clients. I have enabled OAuth 2 signin using one of the app client for [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/explore) integration. Later on signed in a user to IFTTT using the app client. I deleted the user from the user pool [admin_delete_user() by boto3] and it cleared the record in the cognito console, but the funny part is that the user signin is still happening in the IFTTT app. When that happen the user record gets recreated in the Cognito console.

No idea what's happening in the background...

I tried executing the [admin_user_global_sign_out() from boto3]. Still no luck

Comment: What you are saying is that after the user deletion: 1. User can sign in with previous password? This shouldn't happen.
OR 
2. User Sign up (register) again and then sign in? This is an intended behaviour.

Comment: 1. Users can sign in with the previous password. But when the user is recreated in the Cognito console other than username and sub no other attributes is retained.

Comment: Update - I found out that Cognito is creating a new user entity instead of verifying the credentials. This is a unusual behaviour